# How to center arrow on post carousel

Tags: css, wordpress, owl-carousel

My post carousel has two arrows on the side.  I have a background in the shape of a circle for these arrows.  I can't figure out how to center the arrows inside the circles.  Does anyone know how I could do this.  Here is the link to a screenshot of what it currently looks like - 
[image: screenshot]

Here is my css

```css
/*
*  Owl Carousel Owl Demo Theme 
* v1.3.3
*/

.owl-theme .owl-controls{
 margin-top: 50px;
 text-align: center;
}

/* Styling Next and Prev buttons */

.owl-theme .owl-controls .owl-buttons div{
 color: #FFF;
 display: inline-block;
 zoom: 1;
 *display: inline;/*IE7 life-saver */
 margin: 5px;
 padding: 3px 10px;
 font-size: 12px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 30px;
 -moz-border-radius: 30px;
 border-radius: 30px;
 background: #869791;
 filter: Alpha(Opacity=50);/*IE7 fix*/
 opacity: 0.5;


}
/* Clickable class fix problem with hover on touch devices */
/* Use it for non-touch hover action */
.owl-theme .owl-controls.clickable .owl-buttons div:hover{
 filter: Alpha(Opacity=100);/*IE7 fix*/
 opacity: 1;
 text-decoration: none;
}

/* Styling Pagination*/

.owl-theme .owl-controls .owl-page{
 display: inline-block;
 zoom: 1;
 *display: inline;/*IE7 life-saver */
}
.owl-theme .owl-controls .owl-page span{
 display: block;
 width: 12px;
 height: 12px;
 margin: 5px 7px;
 filter: Alpha(Opacity=50);/*IE7 fix*/
 opacity: 0.5;
 -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
 -moz-border-radius: 20px;
 border-radius: 20px;
 background: #869791;
}

.owl-theme .owl-controls .owl-page.active span,
.owl-theme .owl-controls.clickable .owl-page:hover span{
 filter: Alpha(Opacity=100);/*IE7 fix*/
 opacity: 1;
}

/* If PaginationNumbers is true */

.owl-theme .owl-controls .owl-page span.owl-numbers{
 height: auto;
 width: auto;
 color: #FFF;
 padding: 2px 10px;
 font-size: 12px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 30px;
 -moz-border-radius: 30px;
 border-radius: 30px;
}

/* preloading images */
.owl-item.loading{
 min-height: 150px;
 background: url(AjaxLoader.gif) no-repeat center center
}
/* Navigation */
.owl-prev, .owl-next {
  position:absolute;
  top:45%;
padding: 5px;
  margin:0;
  z-index:100;
  font-size:3rem;
  cursor:pointer;
  color:#000000; 

}

.owl-prev {
  left:20px;
opacity: 1 !important;
}

.owl-next {
  right:20px;
opacity: 1 !important;
display: block;
}


.owl-theme .owl-controls .owl-buttons div{
  color: #555;
  display: inline-block;
  zoom: 1;
  *display: inline;/*IE7 life-saver */
  font-size: 3rem;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #ffffff;
  filter: Alpha(Opacity=100);/*IE7 fix*/
  opacity: 1;
  margin-top:-32px;
 width:40px;
 height:40px;
}

.owl-theme .owl-controls .owl-buttons div:hover {
  color:#000000;
    opacity: 1 !important;
  }
```

Comment: Where's your markup? That would be extremely helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without your markup, it's a bit of an educated guess, but after looking at the [owl carousel demo](http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/demos/itemsCustom.html), I believe I can help.

The elements are addressed in this CSS (from your question):

```
.owl-theme .owl-controls .owl-buttons div {
  color: #555;
  display: inline-block;
  /* remove this! */
  zoom: 1;
  /* and this! */
  *display: inline;/*IE7 life-saver */
  font-size: 3rem;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #ffffff;
  /* and remove this! */
  filter: Alpha(Opacity=100);/*IE7 fix*/
  opacity: 1;
  margin-top:-32px;
  width:40px;
  height:40px;
}
```

**Assuming that** your arrows are text and not images, then all you need to do is add line-height to your css:

```
line-height: 40px; /* adjust as needed */
```

NOTE, if you're supporting IE7, I would recommend you *stop*.  IE7 has been dead for some time, and is not worth the effort.

Modified CSS to vertically center the arrows:

```
.owl-theme .owl-controls .owl-buttons div {
  color: #555;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 3rem;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #ffffff;
  opacity: 1;
  margin-top:-32px;
  width:40px;
  height:40px;
  line-height: 40px; /* adjust as needed */
  /* may or may not need this */
  text-align: center;
}
```

Also note that your CSS could be simplified - your `owl-prev` and `owl-next` CSS is the same / conflicting with the `.owl-theme .owl-controls .owl-buttons div` css.

Comment: Thank you, can't believe I missed such a simple fix!